# // This file does not contain any Objective-C runtime information

Tags: ios

I am trying to reverse engineer a file with class-dump but it says objective-c header is not found. This is clearly an objective C file.

````
2023-03-03 22:26:21.789 class-dump[5565:85760] Unknown load command: 0x80000034
2023-03-03 22:26:21.789 class-dump[5565:85760] Unknown load command: 0x80000033
2023-03-03 22:26:21.790 class-dump[5565:85760] Unknown load command: 0x00000032
//
//     Generated by class-dump 3.5 (64 bit).
//
//     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2013 by Steve Nygard.
//

#pragma mark -

//
// File: eLS_LogIn
// UUID: 5C4B35BF-16BC-3EB4-BF3A-D28EF2C53CFA
//
//                           Arch: arm64
//                 Source version: 0.0.0.0.0
//

//
// This file does not contain any Objective-C runtime information.
//```
````

Comment: What type of file are you talking about, an executable or a dylib or something different? Why are you so sure it uses ObjC? May be it uses Swift instead or is somehow obfuscated.  Have you tried to load the file in Ghidra or IDA Pro?

Comment: We don't have enough evidence to evaluate this. For example, what file is this? Why are you sure the file is Objective C? In any case, perhaps the explanation is that the metadata format has changed, and that the `class-dump` tool is no longer able to recognize it.

Comment: https://github.com/AloneMonkey/MonkeyDev/blob/master/bin/class-dump, but it shows the follows now.

eLS_LogIn_output $ ./class-dump eLS_LogIn
2023-03-05 17:43:03.493 class-dump[10275:153208] Unknown load command: 0x80000034
2023-03-05 17:43:03.493 class-dump[10275:153208] Unknown load command: 0x80000033
2023-03-05 17:43:03.493 class-dump[10275:153208] Unknown load command: 0x00000032
2023-03-05 17:43:03.495 class-dump[10275:153208] Error: Cannot find offset for address 0x1000010000d070 in dataOffsetForAddress:

Comment: I am testing an executable

Comment: I have the same error I was able to see the header files using hopper disassembler demo version.